# TooManyRequestsException with Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: php, amazon-product-api, symfony5

I'm starting to develop a simple Symfony 5 application. It uses Amazon Product Advertising API 5.0 with the paapi5-php-sdk package (provided by TheWirecutter, since Amazon pulled it from Packagist, but this is irrelevant).

I've a 5 years old Associate account, and I already generated fresh Access+Secret keys.

Since I'm in Italy, I'm hitting [webservices.amazon.it+eu-west-1](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/common-request-parameters.html#host-and-region).

I've ran, like, 10 API calls in the last 24 hours, but the service always respond:

> TooManyRequests Error Message: The request was denied due to request
> throttling. Please verify the number of requests made per second to
> the Amazon Product Advertising API.

I'm aware of the [rating limiting](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/troubleshooting/api-rates.html), but I'm nowhere near the lowest limit.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As suggested by Denys Gorobchenko, I contacted Amazon. My access to the AAPI has been revoked due to low sales (none). I'm not really sure how I'm expected to develop with it if I don't have access, but I already moved on to other things and I'm not going to research this anymore for now.

Comment: this is really a bad restriction. :(

Comment: Where did you go? Looks like Amazon has a short circuit, and their contact form is also bugged by javascript Promise error, making impossible to contact them for support.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same rate limit error the first time I tried using the API, even though I did have affiliate sales in the past 30 days.

For those in the same situation, what worked for me was simply waiting more time before trying again. I had to wait around **48 hours** and then it started accepting my requests.

Answer (score 0):

Check you account restrictions. The point is Amazon could restrict access to affiliates since they don't produce enough sales at the time. Amazon granted unlimited access till January 2019, so now you account may be considered as "deprecated" as it don't have sales for last 30 days or somthing like that.
Anyway, it is better to address this question to Amazon Associates Support.

Comment: Support form is bugged, if you submit it you will get a raw JSON response telling you to compile the e-mail field, field that is disabled and pre-filled.